# Errors from data type's Show instance

Tags: haskell

I have been working through Gabriel Gonzale's excellent [blog post on Free Monads](http://www.haskellforall.com/2012/06/you-could-have-invented-free-monads.html). To assist my understanding I wanted to create a Show instance for the following type and play around with it in GHCi, the type (from the blog post) is:

```
data Thread m r = Atomic (m (Thread m r)) | Return r
```

And my Show instance is:

```
instance (Show m, Show r) => Show (Thread m r) where
  show (Atomic m x) = "Atomic " ++ show m ++ " " ++ show x
  show (Return x)   = "Return " ++ show x
```

Unfortunately GHCi gives me this error when trying to load the file:

```
• Expected kind ‘* -> *’, but ‘m’ has kind ‘*’
• In the first argument of ‘Thread’, namely ‘m’
  In the first argument of ‘Show’, namely ‘Thread m r’
  In the instance declaration for ‘Show (Thread m r)’
```

So, most importantly: what does this error mean, why am I getting it? I think answering that will help my understanding of the blog post immensely (albeit in a slightly roundabout way).
Also, what would a working Show implementation look like? I tried looking at the instance for Either, but didn't understand what was going on.

Comment: `m` is a *type constructor* like `IO` or `Maybe`. It's not a complete type (like `IO ()` or `Maybe String`). But `m (Thread m r)` is a complete type.

Comment: Additionally the data constructor `Atomic` only takes one argument, not two.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, the error you receive is a *kind* error. A kind is the “type” of a type. Just as types classify values, kinds classify types. And just as Haskell infers types from values, it also infers kinds from types. We use the same symbol `::` to denote that a value has a certain type (e.g., `1 :: Int`) and to denote that a type has a certain kind (e.g., `Int :: *`).

There are two kinds mentioned in the error message: `*` is the kind of types that are inhabited by values, such as `Int` and `Bool`, while `* -> *` is the kind of type *constructors* such as `Maybe`, `[]`, and `IO`. You can think of type constructors as type-level functions: `Maybe` takes a type (of kind `*`) as an argument and returns a type (also of kind `*`) as a result, e.g., `Maybe Int :: *`. Kinds are curried in the same way as functions; for example, `Either` has the kind `* -> * -> *` because it takes two arguments of kind `*` to produce a type of kind `*`:

```
Either :: * -> * -> *
Either Int :: * -> *
Either Int Bool :: *
```

So the error comes from the typeclass constraint on your `Show` instance:

```
instance (Show m, Show r) => Show (Thread m r) where
          ------
```

`Show` is the class of types of kind `*` that can be shown. You can see this by typing `:kind Show` (or `:k Show`) in GHCi:

```
> :kind Show
Show :: * -> Constraint
```

So `Show` takes a type of kind `*` and returns a typeclass constraint. Without getting into too much detail about constraints, this means `Show m` implies that `m :: *`. However, the definition of `Thread` passes an argument to `m` in the definition of its `Atomic` constructor, which has a field of type `m (Thread m r)`. Look at the kind of `Thread`:

```
> :kind Thread
Thread :: (* -> *) -> * -> *
```

That implies that `m :: * -> *`, hence the mismatch.

The next error is in the implementation of your `Show` instance, namely:

```
show (Atomic m x) = "Atomic " ++ show m ++ " " ++ show x
               -                        ----------------
```

Here you’ve provided a pattern that matches multiple fields, but `Atomic` only has one field. You should change the implementation to the following:

```
show (Atomic m) = "Atomic " ++ show m
```

If you remove the `Show m` constraint, you’ll see a more useful error message:

```
Could not deduce (Show (m (Thread m r)))
  arising from a use of ‘show’
from the context (Show r)
  bound by the instance declaration at …
In the second argument of ‘(++)’, namely ‘show m’
In the expression: "Atomic " ++ show m
In an equation for ‘show’: show (Atomic m) = "Atomic " ++ show m
```

This says that you’re trying to call `show` on a value of type `m (Thread m r)` but you don’t have that constraint in the context. So you can add it:

```
instance (Show (m (Thread m r)), Show r) => Show (Thread m r) where
          ---------------------
```

This is not “standard” Haskell, so GHC starts suggesting extensions that allow it:

```
Non type-variable argument in the constraint: Show (m a)
(Use FlexibleContexts to permit this)
In the context: (Show (m a), Show r)
While checking an instance declaration
In the instance declaration for ‘Show (Thread m r)’
```

Let’s try adding `-XFlexibleContexts` (on the command line with `ghci … -XFlexibleContexts`, in a session with `:set -XFlexibleContexts`, or in a source file with `{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}`), since it’s actually a pretty benign extension. Now we get a different error:

```
Variable ‘a’ occurs more often than in the instance head
  in the constraint: Show (m a)
(Use UndecidableInstances to permit this)
In the instance declaration for ‘Show (Thread m r)’
```

We can add `-XUndecidableInstances`—all this means is that you’re writing a type-level computation that GHC can’t prove will halt. Sometimes this is undesirable, but in this case it’s fine, because we know that instance resolution will either find an acceptable `Show` instance or fail. Now the compiler accepts it, and we can try our `Show` instance, say with something simple like `m ~ []` and `r ~ Int`:

```
> Atomic [Atomic [Return 1, Return 2]] :: Thread [] Int
Atomic [Atomic [Return 1,Return 2]]
```

However, note that this won’t work when you set `m` to a type constructor that doesn’t have any `Show` instances, such as `IO`:

```
> Atomic (return (Atomic (return (Return 1) >> return (Return 2)))) :: Thread IO Int

No instance for (Show (IO (Thread IO Int)))
  arising from a use of ‘print’
In a stmt of an interactive GHCi command: print it
```

Additionally, you may also notice that you’re missing some parentheses in the result of your `Show` instance:

```
> Atomic (Right (Atomic (Left "asdf"))) :: Thread (Either String) Int
Atomic Right Atomic Left "asdf"
```

That’s an easy fix that I’ll leave to you.

This should enable your instance to work with a datatype such as `Toy` from the article, by way of `Free`:

```
> Atomic (Free (Output "foo" (Pure (Return "bar"))))
Atomic (Free (Output "foo" (Pure Return ("bar"))))
```

Answer (score 5):

According to `Thread m r = Action (m (Thread m r) | …`, `m` is something that takes a type and returns another type. We call `m` a type constructor or of kind `* -> *`. Another example for something like that is `Maybe`:

```
data Maybe a = Just a | Nothing
```

`Maybe` on it's own isn't a type. You have to provide it another type, e.g. `Maybe Int` or `Maybe String`.

Now `Show` expects a type with kind `*`. But `Thread` needs `* -> *`. Therefore, GHC gives up. Since `Show m` comes before `Thread m r`, GHC thinks its kind is `*`, which does not work for `Action (m (Thread m r))`, since that would need a type constructor (`* -> *`).

This problem, by the way, is why classes like [`Show1`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/prelude-extras-0.4.0.3/docs/Prelude-Extras.html#t:Show1) exist in some packages. You could adopt that and *then* write your `Show` instance:

```
instance (Show1 m, Show r) => Show (Thread m r) where
  show (Atomic x) = "Atomic " ++ show1 x
  show (Return x) = "Return " ++ show x
```

Or you can delve into the realm of [undecidable instances](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/8.0-latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#undecidable-instances) and say that `Thread m r` can be shown if `m (Thread m r)` can be shown:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances #-}

instance (Show r, Show (m (Thread m r))) => Show (Thread m r) where
  show (Atomic x) = "Atomic " ++ show x
  show (Return x) = "Return " ++ show x
```

Comment: This is a great answer, I was even looking at the Either instance of Show and wondering if that Show1 class had relevance. This is absolutely worthy of being the accepted answer, but Jon Purdy's contains a such a great breakdown of the problem I couldn't not mark his as accepted. Just wanted you to know that there's a lot of value in this answer too and thank you for providing it.